# What is "Multi-Scale" Grid Search in SVR Cross Validation

Tags: regression, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to implement an algo that uses epsilon-SVR with a histogram intersection kernel. The slack variable C and the error intensive margin e needs to be optimised. The algo uses an exhaustive mutli-scale grid search in the cross-validation.

I understand exhaustive grid search in cross validation, but not exhaustive multi-scale grid search. What does "multi-scale" exactly mean ?